# Can't upload some of the MP3 file in Codeigniter but other MP3 is uploading

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need help, I don't know what seems the problem it is really weird, because when I am trying to upload some of the MP3 file that I have, some of them are uploading, some of them are not.

I keep having an error like this on my other MP3 FILE. `The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.`

I am using Codeigniter 3.

I already tried updating my mimes.php and Upload.php.

Mimes.php

```
'mp3'=>  array('audio/mpeg’,‘audio/mpeg3’,‘audio/mpg’,‘audio/x-mpeg’,‘audio/mp3’,‘application/force-download’,‘application/octet-stream'),
```

Here is my Controller in uploading the Audio.

```
    public function _do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = 'upload/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp3|mp4';
        $config['file_name'] = round(microtime(true) * 1000); //just milisecond timestamp fot unique name
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('photo')) //upload and validate
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'photo';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Upload error: ' . $this->upload->display_errors('', ''); //show ajax error
            $data['status'] = false;
              echo json_encode($data);// echo json_encode(array('status' => false, "csrf_socratic_app" => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()));
        }
        return $this->upload->data('file_name');
    }
```

I already updated my php.ini on the file max size. I know that the file size has no problem because some of my mp3 is more than 10mb and it is uploading, but other mp3 is not uploading. I really need help, I really don't know what is my error on this.

Here is the difference of the files that I am trying to upload.

[image]

the Audio name `1111.mp3` is not uploading and I Don't know why I keep having an error of `The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.`
While the other two files is uploading.

Comment: What's the difference between a file that _will_ upload, and one that will not? Where is the code that produces the error message? Are those quotes correct in your MIME type definition? You seem to mix single quotes and something else.

Comment: @droopsnoot hi sir i updated my questions. there is no really difference and i dont know on what is wrong with this.

Comment: Probably need to see the code that is producing the error message, then.